# I wont to get sum of Jtable column value (int + float)

Tags: java, jtable

I wont to get the int values and floated values from user input and calculate it and show to Jlabel How can i do that??
I use this code -

```
public int getsum(){

    int sum = 0;
    float Sum = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<jTable2.getRowCount(); i++)
    {
       sum += Integer.parseInt(jTable2.getValueAt(i, 4).toString().trim());
    }
    for (int I=0; I<jTable2.getRowCount(); I++)
    {
       Sum += Integer.parseInt(jTable2.getValueAt((int) I, 4).toString().trim());
    }
    txt_Total_amount.setText(Integer.toString((int) (sum+Sum)));  
    return 0;
}
```

my column data has some values in int and some are float data
So i try to get total of that values in to jLable

in this case i have and error like this -

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "655.5"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
    at bankapplication.Register_customer.getsum(Register_customer.java:75)
    at bankapplication.Register_customer.jButton5ActionPerformed(Register_customer.java:783)
    at bankapplication.Register_customer.access$800(Register_customer.java:27)
    at bankapplication.Register_customer$9.actionPerformed(Register_customer.java:496)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2346)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)........
```

please help me to slove the probleam
give me an ***examples***
thanks

Comment: Do you know the difference between `int` and `float`?

Comment: Your error occurs because you are using the `parseInt()` function to parse a `float`.

Comment: I'm beginner to the java so i don't know what is the difference between int and float,So how can i get values in floated value and int and calculate the some of them

Comment: i change the code like this bur still get an error -                                             int sum = 0;
        float Sum = 0;
        for (int i=0; i<jTable2.getRowCount(); i++)
        {
           sum += Integer.parseInt(jTable2.getValueAt(i, 4).toString().trim());
        }
        for (int I=0; I<jTable2.getRowCount(); I++)
        {
           Sum += Float.parseFloat(jTable2.getValueAt(I, 4).toString().trim());
        }
        txt_Total_amount.setText(Integer.toString(sum)+(Float.toString(Sum)));